# BITS error codes

Tags: windows, http, microsoft-bits, bits-service

I'm writing an application updater that pulls installation package from our distribution web site to the user's PC using the background intelligent download service facility.

More or less everything is working fine now but I'm having a bit of problem getting the application react well to all recoverable errors. Specifically, I'd like the application to handle properly the case of proxy authentication.

In HTTP, it's simple: make a request, get a "407" HTTP response code, prompt for user name/password and repeat until you ether go through or the user press "cancel".

With BITS, it's not that simple. I don't get the HTTP status code. I get a couple of codes: the context (which should be BG_ERROR_CONTEXT_REMOTE_FILE in my case) and an "ErrorCode" that is supposed to depend on the context.

If I request the textual description of the error through GetErrorDescription, I get the correct "407 proxy authentication require" text. But the error code I have is 0x80190197 which is nowhere near 407.

So, does anyone know where I can get a full list of the BITS error code ? Failing that, partial list with the most common errors would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0x80190197 is not strictly speaking a BITS error, it's an HTTP stack error. The list is available here: [Errors (019) FACILITY_HTTP](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joshpoley/archive/2008/01/07/errors-019-facility-http.aspx)